# The currentTime property not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I want to show a specific frame of a video by scrolling like [this website(Apple Macbook)](https://www.apple.com/macbook/). Setting the currentTime property seems to work in Firefox and Safari, however, it does not work in Chrome. I think the event type "loadedmetadata" is wrong for Chrome to add the event listener. The code is below.

HTML & JS

```js
(function(document) {
  var video;
  $(function() {
    init();
  });

  function init() {
    video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
      setClick();
      setScroll();
    });
  }

  function setClick() {
    $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
      video.currentTime = 2;
    });
  }

  function setScroll() {
    $(window).on('scroll', setFrame);
  }

  function setFrame() {
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(pos);
    video.currentTime = pos/5;
  }

})(document);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>funny thing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="myButton">i am button</button>
  <video id="myVideo" controls height="800" preload="metadata">
    <source src="test.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me on Chrome if you just give it a valid url, your snippet won't work because `test.mp4` does not exist. Here is a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehd43wjm/) and a snippet:

```js
(function(document) {
  var video;
  $(function() {
    init();
  });

  function init() {
    video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
      setClick();
      setScroll();
    });
  }

  function setClick() {
    $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
      video.currentTime = 2;
    });
  }

  function setScroll() {
    $(window).on('scroll', setFrame);
  }

  function setFrame() {
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(pos);
    video.currentTime = pos/5;
  }

})(document);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>funny thing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="myButton">i am button</button>
  <video id="myVideo" controls height="200" preload="metadata">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, however, I think if I run this code snippet at "localhost:8000" and not uploading files, it might not work. Do you know why such a thing happens?

Comment: Anyway, after I uploaded these files to the server, it works.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, certainly it's because it couldn't load the video, but I'm not a big server mechanics guy.